# Calling a java script function from Kendo UI button

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I currently have an CF page that has a link to call a function:

```
<a href="javascript:updatepreferences();" id="prefbutton" style="background-color:#BDBDBD"></strong>User Preferences</strong></a>
```

I want to accomplish the same thing with a Kendo UI button. But i do not know how to set it up correctly. This is what I have attempted:

```
 <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <div>
                        <button id="userPref" class="k-primary">User Peference</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    function onClick(e) {
                        e.updatepreferences();
                    }

                    $("userPerf").kendoButton({
                        click: onClick
                    });

                });
            </script>

            <style>
                .demo-section {
                    line-height: 4em;
                }
                .demo-section .k-button {
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }
            </style>

            </div>
```

I am a novice so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
<button id="button" type="button">Edit</button>
<script>
$("#button").kendoButton({
    click: function(e) {
        alert(e.event.target.tagName);
    }
});
</script>
```